# How to import GitHub and Bitbucket repositories into Eclipse Mars?

Tags: eclipse, git, github, bitbucket, egit

I installed Eclipse Mars enabled the Git perspective and imported a repository. It looks fine, but Eclipse is not behaving normal I can't create new files and search is not finding anything outside the file I'm in. What is the proper way to import repositories/projects from GitHub, Bitbucket and other Git Hosts?

Comment: Repositories are separate from projects. You first clone repository and then import projects into workspace from it. Once you have a repo follow [EGit documentation on importing project](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Importing_projects).

Answer (score 10):

First you need to clone the (git) repository in Eclipse.

**Steps to clone git repo in Eclipse**

- Go to GitHub, or BitBucket, and copy the URL of the repo to clone
- In Eclipse, Open the perspective *Git*
- Use the shortcut icon *Clone a Git Repository ...* (the icons are shown on the view *Git Repositories*)
- The dialog *Clone Git Repository* opens, with the page *Source Git Repository*
- (The url of the git repo, should already be filled in, at the field *uri*)

**TIP:** The field *uri* can not be edited. Use the other field, like *Host*, *repository Path*, etc to correct the url if required.

- Press the button *Next*
- The page *Branch Selection* opens
- All branches from the remote git repository are now shown
- (Mark the branches you like to clone, by default all branches are checked for cloning)
- Press the button *Next*
- The page *Local Destination* opens
- Make sure you select the correct location, where the local clone of the repository should go (something like `/home/<user>/git`)

**TIP:** Make sure that you do **NOT** clone the git repository inside the Eclipse workspace directory!

- Select from the drop-down *Initial branch* the branch you like to start working on. (Default is the *master* branch. Can also easily be changed later.)
- Press the button *Finish*, to start the cloning job.

After successful cloning of the git repository, the project(s) in the git repository can be imported into Eclipse as (Eclipse) projects.

**Import project in Eclipse**

Open the Eclipse perspective *Java*

**Maven Project**

*This will import Maven project(s) (based on `pom.xml` file(s)) as Eclipse project(s)*

- From the view *Package Explorer* select right mouse button menu: *Import...* or use the Eclipse menu: *File -> Import...*
- The dialog *Import* opens, with the page *Select*
- Select from the tree: *Maven -> Existing Maven Projects*
- Press the button *Next*
- The page *Maven Project* opens
- Choose the *Root Directory* to scan for Maven projects. Use the button *Browse*, to go to the just cloned git repository (`/home/<user>/git`)
- Once the location is selected, the *Projects* should appear, in the form of located `pom.xml` files.
- (Normally all projects are selected. At a 2nd import, some may be grayed out, as they already exist in the Eclipse Package Explorer, as project)
- Press the button *Finish* to import the Maven project as Eclipse projects

**Eclipse**

*In case the git projects do contain the typical Eclipse configuration files / directory (like: `.project`, `.classpath`, `.settings`), then they can be imported as Standard Eclipse projects*

- From the view *Package Explorer* select right mouse button menu: *Import...* or use the Eclipse menu: *File -> Import...*
- The dialog *Import* opens, with the page *Select*
- Select from the tree: *General -> Existing Projects into Workspace*
- Press the button *Next*
- Choose the *Select Root Directory* to scan for Eclipse projects. Use the button *Browse*, to go to the just cloned git repository (`/home/<user>/git`)
- (Select from the *Options* the check box *Search for nested projects* in case the imported project contains nested Eclipse projects)
- (Normally all projects are selected. At a 2nd import, some may be grayed out, as they already exist in the Eclipse Package Explorer, as project)
- Press the button *Finish* to import the Maven project as Eclipse projects

Comment: If you install JBoss Tools or the separate pieces mentioned in https://wiki.eclipse.org/E4/UI/Smart_Import , then you get an EGit import wizard that is able to "discover" and import projects of different type (.project, Maven...) as once without having user to pick the right wizard.

Answer (score 3):

**Prerequisites GitHub/Bitbucket:**

Get an GitHub/Bitbucket account.

- List item
- Create a new repository in GitHub/Bitbucket
- Make a branch of your "master" in your new repository, 
  it is good practice not to do changes in directly in the "master" but merging the changes from a branch.

**Prerequisites on your computer:**

- Install Eclipse Mars

**Setup the git project in Eclipse**

- Open perspective "Resource"

  - Menu:  Window / Perspective / Open Perspective / Other  and choose "Resource"
- Import your GitHub/Bitbucket branch

  - Menu:  File / Import, a wizard opens
  - Wizard (Select): Under "Git" choose "Project from Git" and press "Next"
  - Wizard (Select Repository Source): Choose "Clone URI" and press "Next"
  - Wizard (Source Git Repository):
    At top "Location / URI:" paste in your GitHub/Bitbucket Url. (In GitHub/Bitbucket site right click your repository link and choose copy link address)
  - Under Authentication fill in your GitHub/Bitbucket user and password and press "Next"
  - Wizard (Branch Selection): Only check your branch, deselect all others and press "Next"
  - Wizard (Local Destination): Choose a folder  where you like to keep your git project, don't put it in your workspace folder and press "Next".
  - Wizard (Select a wizard to use for importing projects): Select "Import as general project" and press "Next"
  - Wizard (Import projects): Press "Finish"

The project should now be visible in the "Project Explorer"

**Create the ".gitignore" file**

This is importent or your code will be mixed with Eclipse files

In "Project Explorer" right click your project folder an then New / File enter ".gitignore" at the "File Name" prompt and press "Finish"

Paste the following in to the file.

```
# eclipse specific git ignore
*.pydevproject
.project
.metadata
bin/**
tmp/**
tmp/**/*
*.tmp
*.bak
*.swp
*~.nib
local.properties
.classpath
.settings/
.loadpath
```

**Finally keep your Eclipse project in sync with GitHub/Bitbucket**

- Menu:  Window / Perspective / Open Perspective / Other  and choose "Git"
- In the "Git Perspective" drag files from "Unstaged Changes" to "Staged Changes" Enter a "Commit Message" describing your code changes and finally press "Commit and Push"

Comment: If you install JBoss Tools or the separate pieces mentioned in https://wiki.eclipse.org/E4/UI/Smart_Import , then you get an EGit import wizard that is able to "discover" and import projects of different type (.project, Maven...) as once without having user to pick the right wizard.